# Convert varchar to int in case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to have case statement that converts 1,2...5 into Main.District 1,Main.District 2...Main.District 5.

This is what I have so far:

```
CASE 
    WHEN Pubworks.dbo.csc.DistID = 1 THEN 
    'MAINT. DISTRICT 1' 
    WHEN Pubworks.dbo.csc.DistID = 2 THEN 
    'MAINT. DISTRICT 2' 
     ......
    WHEN Pubworks.dbo.csc.DistID = 5 THEN 
    'MAINT. DISTRICT 5' 
    ELSE    
    Pubworks.dbo.csc.DistID
    end
    as District
```

How do I convert the varchar value to a data type int? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is `DistID` an `INT` or a `VARCHAR`?

Comment: What field is of varchar type? Is `DistID` an `int`?

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 2):

With `CASE` expressions, all of the values must be of the same type.  You're getting an error because you're mixing two types as possible outcomes: `INT` and `VARCHAR`.

Assuming `DistID` is an `INT`, you can do the following:

```
Case    
    When Pubworks.dbo.csc.DistID In (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 
        Then Concat('MAINT. DISTRICT ', Pubworks.dbo.csc.DistID)
    Else
        Convert(Varchar, Pubworks.dbo.csc.DistID)
End As District
```

Assuming it's a `VARCHAR`, you can do this instead:

```
Case    
    When Pubworks.dbo.csc.DistID In ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5') 
        Then Concat('MAINT. DISTRICT ', Pubworks.dbo.csc.DistID)
    Else
        Pubworks.dbo.csc.DistID
End As District
```

Comment: Question though: how were you able to only have one `when` statement and not have to create five separate ones?

Comment: @tryingtolearn The `IN()` essentially expands into `OR` statements, so having `DistID IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` it's saying `WHERE DistID = 1 OR DistID = 2 OR ...`.  And since all of the options follow the same pattern for the outcome, we can just use `CONCAT('MAINT. DISTRICT ', Pubworks.dbo.csc.DistID)` to capture all cases.